# How to include script with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, navbar, ngroute

I used yeoman to generate an angularjs project. I want to use [ng-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-breadcrumbs) so I installed it and when I try to add angular.module('ab', ['ngRoute', 'ng-breadcrumbs']) I have an error 
Failed to instantiate module ng-breadcrumbs due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ng-breadcrumbs' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
I guess I have to load the js file but where ? I don't understand where yeoman do that ? I can't find any loaded file . Shall I just do it in root.html ? or index.html ? 
Other question, I am suing angular ui router, it works with ng-breadcrumbs too or I have to use ngRoute ? 
I can't find script src="angular.js" in any file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `ng-breadcrumbs.min.js` after including `angular.min.js` in your index.html.

If you are planning to use `ngRoute`, you have to include `angular-route.js`.
Dependency injection would be `angular.module('yourApp', ['ngRoute']);`

If you are using UI Router, you have to include `angular-ui-router.min.js`.
Dependency injection would be `angular.module('yourApp', ['ui.router']);`

ng-breadcrumbs could be used with ng-route as presented [here](https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-breadcrumbs)

Answer (score 0):

In index.html right after script src="angular.js" you have to add ng-breadcrumbs javascript source.

You can install it via

```
bower install ng-breadcrumbs --save
```

then add to index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/ng-breadcrumbs/dist/ng-breadcrumbs.min.js">
```

Comment: there is no script src="angular.js" in any file